# Is this necessary to set frame Rate in Unity android game?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, optimization, scripting, lag

I want to know is it necessary to set application frame rate in Unity's android game script?

What is the best frame rate for android ? 30 fps or 60 fps ?
What if we do not set it? is it affect on game performance ?

Because my game has lag in some devices and it's genre is First Person Shooter.
Could it be because I did not specify the frame rate of the game?

Because I've been optimizing my game scripts as far as I can.
And in unity's `profiller` I checked my scripts and i didn't see any serious problem.

But some time's I have lag when i turning around. I mean when player looks around, some times he rotate about 180 degree or more quickly when lag is happening.

Here is part of my mouse look code :

```
void Update()
        {
          the_time = Time.deltaTime;
          if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (Touch t in Input.touches)
                {
                    if (t.position.x > Screen.width / 2)
                    {
                        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                        {
                            delta = t.deltaPosition;
                        }
                        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began || t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                        {
                            delta = -t.deltaPosition;
                            rotX += (delta.y * sensitivityX * current_speed_offset_vertical * the_time);
                            rotY -= delta.x * sensitivityY * current_speed_offset * the_time;

                            rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -clampAngle, clampAngle);

                            TlocalEurlar.y = rotY;
                            transform.eulerAngles = TlocalEurlar;

                            x_rot_transform_Eurlar.x = rotX;
                            x_rot_transform.localEulerAngles = x_rot_transform_Eurlar;

                        }
                        else if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                        {
                            delta = t.deltaPosition;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Is there a problem with my script?
Can this problem be related to not setting the frame rate of the game?

Comment: No it's fine .. I don't see where lag should come from in that script. If you don't set a frame rate it uses whatever frame rate in can archive .. afaik the frame rate is only to limit frame rate on the top .. you can't force to reach a certain frame rate at the bottom ^^

Comment: You should print out the frame rate of the game on device. This is how to: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-i-display-fps-on-android-device.386250/

Your scene might be too heavy for the device to render. Some view directions might be heavier than others, and so it leads to frame rate drop and make the rotation jagged.

The default frame rate is 60fps, but it might not be possible to reach that fps on device. So limitation of frame rate to a lower value might be helpful.

Script is not the only thing that should be optimized. If you bought from asset store, use the mobile version.